# How to edit the color of attribute values in XML Doc comments?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xmldocument

I've made my own Visual Studio theme in the 2013 version and now I'm migrating to 2015. Since the font and color settings on XML Doc comments changed, I had to reconfigure the color for the XML comments. However, the color is not applied for the attributes values.

Here we can see it's black but supposed to be green.

[image: Supposed to be green]

Here's what the options look like:
[image: options]

Pretty much all the options starting with "XML" are set to green, so I suppose there's another manipulation to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are looking for is under Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Identifier. This will unfortunately change all class names, methods names, and variable names. You cannot change the attribute color without on its own. Please see [Visual Studios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545.aspx) for a full list of how the items relate to color changes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I fell here and so will more people.

The selected answer is correct. **However**, there's an easy way to "have your cake and eat it too!" i.e., have that `XML Doc Attribute` whatever color you want without surrendering color options for the other items.

The `Identifier` indeed sets the `XML Doc Attribute` color. However, you can use a free extension, such as [SemanticColorizer (at VS Marketplace)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer) which allows you to override the rest of your code item's colors, as I did:

[image: sane code coloring]

I manually configured the colors like the Monokai theme. As you can see here, the `XML Doc Attribute` ("typeOfTrade") is grey, which is set by the `Identifier`. By using the extension, I can give any color I want to other items that otherwise would've inherited that grey from the `Identifier`.

From their marketplace page:

> A Visual Studio 2015, 2017 & 2019 editor extension for semantic syntax
> highlighting.
>
> It uses the Roslyn APIs to highlight the following syntax types in
> distinctive colors to make them easily recognizable.
>
> To change the colors use the regular Visual Studio "Font and Colors"
> Options. Look for Semantic * in the "Display items".
>
> This extension works for the first final version of Visual Studio 2015
> and all sucessors.

From my config:

[image]